# Check iOS version at runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is sort of a follow on from my last question. I am using `beginAnimations:context:` to setup an animation block to animate some UITextLabels. However I noticed in the docs that is says: *"Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods instead."*

My question is I would love to use animateWithDuration:animations: (available in iOS 4.0 and later) but do not want to exclude folks using iOS 3.0. Is there a way to check to iOS version of a device at runtime so that I can make a decision as to which statement to use?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version thread.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In many cases you do not need to check iOS version directly, instead of that you can check whether particular method is present in runtime or not.

In your case you can do the following:

```
if ([[UIView class] respondsToSelector:@selector(animateWithDuration:animations:)]){
// animate using blocks
}
else {
// animate the "old way"
}
```

Comment: `[[UIView class] respondsToSelector:@selector(animateWithDuration:animations:)]` can be written as `[UIView respondsToSelector:@selector(animateWithDuration:animations:)]`

Comment: I hate blanket statements. There are use cases where you must check the iOS version. I'm facing such a use case right now!!!

Comment: @JohnConnor, you're right in some cases you may need to check iOS version but in general you should avoid that if possible. Just curious, what's your case?

Comment: @JustinKredible, me too. In my case, if Location Services is disabled/denied for my app, I want to proactively direct them to the Settings App ... except the options differ between iOS 5 and iOS 6. How else will I be able to give the user proper direction than through knowing if they're on iOS 6 or not?

Answer (score 58):

Simpler solution for anyone who'll need help in the future:

```
NSArray *versionCompatibility = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ( 5 == [[versionCompatibility objectAtIndex:0] intValue] ) { /// iOS5 is installed

    // Put iOS-5 code here

} else { /// iOS4 is installed

    // Put iOS-4 code here         

}
```

Comment: you could also have used the `NSNumericSearch` compare option ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1990854/429521

Comment: This is great because unlike the current accepted answer I need to know which iOs version the user is operating because certain unicode character are functioning differently pre iOS6 (like /u200b which has a length of 0 on periOS6 but a length of 1 on postiOS6)

Comment: It should also be noted that you should say `if (5 <= ...)` this way if they come out with a newer iOs version (i.e. iOS6) your app will still support your features!

Comment: Yes, very true. I wrote that in a rush last year. I'm going to adjust it now.

Comment: Actually, I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. Maybe they want something specific in iOS 6, that's not in iOS 5, so they'll have to modify it anyway. Thank you for your suggestion and kind words.

Answer (score 19):

to conform to version specified in system defines

//#define __IPHONE_2_0     20000
//#define __IPHONE_2_1     20100
//#define __IPHONE_2_2     20200
//#define __IPHONE_3_0     30000
//#define __IPHONE_3_1     30100
//#define __IPHONE_3_2     30200
//#define __IPHONE_4_0     40000
You can write function like this
( you should probably store this version somewhere rather than calculate it each time ):

```
+ (NSInteger) getSystemVersionAsAnInteger{
    int index = 0;
    NSInteger version = 0;

    NSArray* digits = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSEnumerator* enumer = [digits objectEnumerator];
    NSString* number;
    while (number = [enumer nextObject]) {
        if (index>2) {
            break;
        }
        NSInteger multipler = powf(100, 2-index);
        version += [number intValue]*multipler;
        index++;
    }
return version;
}
```

Then you can use this as follows:

```
if([Toolbox getSystemVersionAsAnInteger] >= __IPHONE_4_0)
{
  //blocks
} else 
{
  //oldstyle
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Xcode 7 added the `available` syntax making this relatively more simple:

Swift:

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    // iOS 9 only code
} 
else {
   // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Xcode 9 also added this syntax to Objective-C

Objective-C:

```
if (@available(iOS 9.0, *)) {
   // iOS 9 only code
} else {
   // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to exclude entire Objective-C methods or classes in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 7):

Most of these solutions on here are so overkill. All you need to do is `[[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion intValue]`. This automatically removes the decimal, so there is no need to split the string.

So you can just check it like:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion intValue] >= 8) {
    // iOS 8.0 and above
} else {
    // Anything less than iOS 8.0
}
```

You can also define a macro with this code:

```
#define IOS_VERSION [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion intValue];
```

or even include your check:

```
#define IOS_8PLUS ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion intValue] >= 8)
```

Then you just need to do:

```
if (IOS_8PLUS) {
    // iOS 8.0 and above
} else {
    // Anything less than iOS 8.0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Discouraged is not the same as deprecated.

If you need to support earlier versions of iOS that do not have the block based methods, there is nothing wrong with using the older methods (as long as they haven't been removed, of course).

Comment: Honestly, if you don't need the features of the block based methods, I see nothing wrong with the older method.

Comment: Suggest this be made into a comment or useful information added to make this an answer. Unsure why it's up voted...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the version of the Foundation framework to determine the current system version.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1){

//for earlier versions

} else {

//for iOS 7

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For my purposes I've written a tiny library that abstracts away the underlying C calls and presents an Objective-C interface.

```
GBDeviceDetails deviceDetails = [GBDeviceInfo deviceDetails];
if (deviceDetails.iOSVersion >= 6) {
    NSLog(@"It's running at least iOS 6");      //It's running at least iOS 6
}
```

Apart from getting the current iOS version, it also detects the hardware of the underlying device, and gets info about the screen size; all at runtime.

It's on github: [GBDeviceInfo](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo). Licensed under Apache 2.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your Prefix.pch file

```
#define IOS_VERSION [[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] firstObject] intValue]
```

And then you can check iOS versions like:

```
if(IOS_VERSION == 8)
{
     // Hello 8!
}
else
{
     // Hello some other version!
}
```

Off course if you can use feature detection (and it makes sense for your use case) you should do that.

Answer (score 1):

In MonoTouch:

To get the Major version use:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split('.')[0]
```

For minor version use:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split('.')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit nicer and more efficient adaptation to the above solutions:

```
-(CGPoint)getOsVersion
{
    static CGPoint rc = {-1,-1};
    if (rc.x == -1) {
        NSArray *versionCompatibility = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        rc.x = [versionCompatibility[0] intValue];
        rc.y = [versionCompatibility[1] intValue];
    }
    return rc;
}
```

now you can

```
if ([self getOsVersion].x < 7) {
}
```

HTH

Comment: Ah, the old CGPoint approach eh?