# run-time vs. compile-time iPhone version check

Tags: iphone, ios, runtime, version, compile-time

What's the difference between run-time, e.g., `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`, and compile-time, e.g., `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` checking? When should you one over the other?

Is`__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` just a variable set in Build Settings?

I've read the answers to [How to target a specific iPhone version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820142/how-to-target-a-specific-iphone-version) and other related questions listed below.

But, I just noticed that `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED = 30200` when I build & run on iPhone (4.3.1) with Xcode 4. Why?

When you submit your code to Apple, do they compile a version of it for each version of the iPhone that exists, setting `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` accordingly?

That way, you could inspect `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`, and know what iOS version is running the code.

#### Related Questions:

- [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)
- [Check iOS version at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862933/check-ios-version-at-runtime)
- [How to check if iOS version supports library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056761/how-to-check-if-ios-version-supports-library)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` is indeed just a build setting, which you can use in the preprocessor to modify code before compilation. No, Apple doesn't compile your code for each iPhone. They can't, since you don't give them the code. You can use compile time checking to determine, for example, if you need to compile code to emulate a new feature in older OS versions. However, you use runtime version checking to determine whether you should use the built in or emulated version of that feature.

For example, iAds were added in 4.0. You currently support 4.0 and later, but plan on adding support for 3.2 in the future. You make code to display other ads in older versions, using runtime checking to determine whether you should use iAds or other, but you don't want it to be in any releases until the rest of the application is ready for 3.2, since it will make your application larger. You use compile time checking so that the preprocessor leaves that code out of your releases. By using the minimum version macro, you can easily add the code to your release by changing the minimum version build setting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` is just the value for "iOS Deployment Target" under "Build Settings." Make sure the correct target, not the project, is selected.

And, `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` corresponds to the "Base SDK" build setting.

Comment: Use `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` to check xcode compiler version. If Xcode version is not latest enough, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The Compile and Run time or programing words which will be used by the developer. So the best example of compile time is the writing time of the code like importing syntax and declaring properities and methods.and ARC is the compile time programing. And coming to RUNTime after writing the code by the developer is going to execute the program is called runtime. In this time the code will be compiled and will face run time errors like crashing programs and fourse closes unexpected behaviour of the program like that.

Please find the below url For more details

http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/compile_time_vs_runtime