# Cocos2d game doesnt launch on some devices

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, cocos2d-iphone

I're released an iPad game which is developed on the Cocos2d framework. Ive tested the game on a number of devices iPad 3, and iPad 2 and never had any issues.

Now i'm getting a few reports back that its not launching properly on some devices. People are saying they are seeing the default.png images then the app is closing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Idea #1: [crash report.](http://emclstcd.tk)

Comment: I've not used crash reports, how do I enable crash reports from people who have downloaded the app. Ive seen it on iTunes connect, but do I need to enable it somewhere in my programming.

Ive tested the gae on around 6 devices and never seen the crash. It seems to be happening with maybe 1 in 100 users.

Comment: You won't get anything useful then (given the lack of debugging symbols).

Comment: So is there essentially not a lot I can do at this stage?

Comment: Most probable cause: app is not designed to behave well with iOS 6's new autorotation mechanism. Especially if you're using an older cocos2d version. You should try to test on simulator, but not all of these issues may appear in the simulator. Also be sure to check autorotation of any UIKit views (movie player, game center, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was to do with the social framework running on older devices where it isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Without crash report this is just a guessing game.

By all means try to reproduce the problem on your side.

Possible problems:

```
1. If the app takes too long to launch it will be closed by iOS. 
2. If it does not have enough memory it will not launch as well.
```

Try the following:

```
I. Open many other heavy apps in the background so there is not much memory.
See how it affects your app launch. 

II. During launch try to use as many fast taps as possible and fast gestures. 
There is possibility that very early taps are not serviced properly or at all  
and that can cause the crash.

III. Test on many devices as you can - especially low end.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've managed to find the issue, its crashes out when it can't find the social framework obviously not available on devices running below iOS6. 

Interestingly its not going to crash when the Compose view controller is called because its in an if statement to see if its available, it crashes when looking for the framework itself.

Any ideas how I can only import it if its available...if that makes sense?

Comment: I am glad than advice nr III worked.
You may try so called weak linking and respond to selector approach:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697058/when-to-use-respondstoselector-in-objective-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056761/how-to-check-if-ios-version-supports-library