# Comparing strings with the format "2.0.1", "2.0.09"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, string-comparison

I need to get the user's app version number and compare it with the current app version on my server. If the user's app version is lower, then he will get a pop-up to update his app. While doing this, I need to compare the version of the app with the versions that are available. How can I compare the strings which are in the format `"2.0.1"` and `"2.0.09"` and get the highest one, in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6):

How about using the [`compare:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410893-compare?language=occ) method of the NSString class?

```
NSString *v1 = @"2.0.1";
NSString *v2 = @"2.1";

NSComparisonResult result = [v1 compare:v2 options:NSNumericSearch];
if (result == NSOrderedSame || result == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // do
} else {
    // do
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your strings are all of the form "2.0.1" etc. you can just compare them as is with the right options:

```
([localVersionString compare:currentVersionString
                     options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);
```

The above would return "`YES`" if the localVersion is no older than the currentVersion on the server, and "`NO`" otherwise (assuming I have this the right way round).

This is the usual thing to do when checking the local version of iOS installed on an iDevice.

Comment: NSNumericSearch is a much better option than doing it manually.

Answer (score 3):

As answered in this post; [Compare version numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978456/compare-version-numbers-in-objective-c)

Check out my NSString category that implements easy version checking on github; https://github.com/stijnster/NSString-compareToVersion

```c
[@"1.2.2.4" compareToVersion:@"1.2.2.5"];
```

This will return a **NSComparisonResult** which is more accurate than using;

```c
[@"1.2.2" compare:@"1.2.2.5" options:NSNumericSearch]
```

Helpers are also added;

```c
[@"1.2.2.4" isOlderThanVersion:@"1.2.2.5"];
[@"1.2.2.4" isNewerThanVersion:@"1.2.2.5"];
[@"1.2.2.4" isEqualToVersion:@"1.2.2.5"];
[@"1.2.2.4" isEqualOrOlderThanVersion:@"1.2.2.5"];
[@"1.2.2.4" isEqualOrNewerThanVersion:@"1.2.2.5"];
```

Comment: thanks Stijnster, your category is great……but going to really need a Swift version soon…