# Xcode Decimal x.x.x

Tags: objective-c, double, nsdecimalnumber, nsdecimal

xcode can use Decimal 3 place?

Example:

```
NSDecimal *test = 1.0.0; //not work
double test = 1.0.0; //not work
float test = 1.0.0; //not work
```

Can I use decimal 3 place in xcode?

Comment: Um, no? That's not a usual numeric notation. What are you trying to do?

Comment: my wsdl call string data is 1.0.3 and plistflie is 1.0.2 ,I need to use decimal 3 place for check if,I try to convert string data to double but can use just 1.0

Comment: Objective-C is not Java.  Things don't get autoboxed without a bit more syntax than this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two version numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594257/comparing-two-version-numbers)

Comment: oh I don't know keyword but its work thanks again Greg Hewgill

Answer (score 0):

Version numbers like `1.0.3` are neither floating point nor decimal numbers. If you need to store them in a variable, use a string:

```
NSString *test = @"1.0.0";
```

Comment: Thanks Greg Hewgill,I'm used
 
if (![wsdlplist isEqual:plistversion])   

but I can't check if (>,=,<)

Comment: Ah, so you want to *compare* version numbers. Why didn't you say so in your question!

Comment: Comparing version strings is pretty hard actually. Sparkle has some open source code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use string and `componentsSeparatedByString:` method and then convert each object in array to appropriate format.