# Best way to compare "versioning" strings in Swift

Tags: swift

I need to compare 2 strings that represent versions, like `1.2.4` and `2.3.6`. 
I'd like to know if already exists some similar implementation in swift. Maybe something similar to the `systemInfo` function for `UIDevice`. If not, which is in your opinion a good way to perform this check?

Comment: The referenced question was originally for Objective-C, but has a [Swift answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29230214/1187415) as well.

Comment: I saw only the Objective-C answer, shame on me :/

Answer (score 12):

A good way is the `compare:` method with option `.NumericSearch`

```
let version1 = "1.2.4"
let version2 = "2.3.6"

let result = version1.compare(version2, options: .numeric)
switch result {
case .orderedSame : print("versions are equal")
case .orderedAscending : print("version1 is less than version2")
case .orderedDescending : print("version1 is greater than version2")
}
```

Comment: It works. I found this strange issue though. IF I compare 2.0 with 2.0.0 this function returns that 2.0.0 is greater than 2.0

Comment: Yes, but usually version numbers with minor and patch value of zero are displayed as x.0 rather than x.0.0 and x.0.1 > x.0 is correctly recognized.