# Convert NSString value to double

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

In my case, I have two `NSString` values. First one is Current_version and second one is Last_version. Current_version & Last_version value came from my html file. This 2 string contains value like this:

- Last_version = 1.0.2
- Current_version = 1.0.9

I want to convert value without losing any data. Now I want to display those version which are greater then last_version.

So I want to compare these two values.

Comment: These are not double (there are "two points"). You need to compare each part : major/minor/patch one by one. If `NSString *last_version = @"1.0.2";`, you can use `NSArray *lastVersionComponents = [last_version componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];` (same for current_version), and check `[lastVersionComponents[i] integerValue]` vs `[currentVersionCompoents[i] integerValue]`, where i in our case is 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString *lastVersionString = [Last_version stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
NSString *newVersionString =[Current_version stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
float current = [newVersionString floatValue];
float old = [lastVersionString floatValue];
```

Comment: No. Suppose `Current version is 1.1` and `last version is 1.0.9`. Then what to do

Comment: If the versions are 1.0.22 and 1.0.1 ?

Comment: then you need to compare version number , 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978456/compare-version-numbers-in-objective-c

Comment: instead of asking to convert it into float ,