# How to target app version in Firebase RemoteConfig for some build version and greater using contains regex in conditions?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to make a condition to only target some specific App build and greater. For example I want to target App version 26 and above. Is that possible to do? what is the right syntax for the regex?

and I know according to Firebase documentation, it's the **CFBundleVersion** and not the CFBundleShortVersionString.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I came up with and it has some limitations:

**`^0.0.([1-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$`**

For example: this will allow the following range 0.0.11-999

in my case my build version is 0.0.10, so I wanna target anything greater than 0.0.10. My new build version 0.0.15

**Limitations:**
Any number that ends with 0 will return false, so to solve it don't use the following numbers as a build version 20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90

You can test your condition using this great tool:
https://regex101.com

Comment: Not sure but did you check for versions comparing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978456/compare-version-numbers-in-objective-c) ?

Comment: I think you mean something else...this will be used in Firebase > Remote Configs > Conditions > Contains Regex field not inside Xcode or anything

Answer (score 0):

It became available now with greater than, lower than and equals according to this blog post
https://firebase.blog/posts/2020/10/improved-version-targeting-in-remote