# How to show a view controller only one time after update?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to know how to show a simple view controller after the user update the application with App Store ?

For example:

The current version is 3.0.3 and there an update in the store (3.1). When the user open the app after update I would like to show (only for the first time) a view controller.

I've already code this:

```
     NSString *appVersion = NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
 if (appVersion != nil) {
      NSString *currentVersion = [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"CurrentVersion"];
      if (![currentVersion isEqualToString:appVersion] && ![currentVersion isEqual:@"3.0"]) {
           [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setObject:appVersion forKey:@"CurrentVersion"];
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showwelcome" sender:nil];
      }
 }
```

Comment: And what is your main question? this code works... do you want to improve it? or?

Comment: Yes I would like to improve it. This code work but maybe there is a better solution !

Comment: It would be better to use `NSComparisonResult` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978456/compare-version-numbers-in-objective-c