# how to store a value like "2.3.1" in Numbers in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, numbers, nsdecimalnumber

I want to store a value something like 3.2.7  in Numbers in iOS,
coz I want to compare the value with other.

Is there any data type is available? or any tricks?

anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: 3.2.7 is not a number. You should save it as a string. Btw, you can compare string as well as compare a number.

Comment: It's like `version` number. Maybe you could divide it into `MAJOR`.`MINOR`.`PATCH` numbers with `struct` or `class`.

Comment: @AechoLiu will try , thanks for the help

Comment: You can consider saving it as an `IndexPath`. This type can be initialized with an int array (`IndexPath(indexes: [3,2,7])`) and it it already conforms to `Comparable`.

Comment: @Lutz but I'm working in Objective C. IndexPath is in swift only.So, it doesn't

Comment: @Dineshprabu It exists in Objective-C as well. It's called `NSIndexPath` and is also comparable `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSIndexPath *)otherObject;`
Initialization is a little less convenient, though.

Comment: Unclear what "in Numbers" is supposed to mean. Please show actual input including object type, and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a duplicate of [Compare version numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978456/compare-version-numbers-in-objective-c).

As the accepted answer there tells you, strings like `@"3.2.1"` and `@"2.3.7"` are strings, not numbers — but they can be compared in the intuitively numeric way as version strings, by calling `compare:options:` with the NSNumericSearch option.

And if that doesn't quite satisfy your needs, other answers provide many useful tweaks to the comparison algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to implement something like that in Swift you could probably get away with something like the following:

```
struct Version: Comparable, Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: Version, rhs: Version) -> Bool {
         return lhs.maj == rhs.maj && lhs.min == rhs.min && lhs.patch == rhs.patch
    }

    static func < (lhs: Version, rhs: Version) -> Bool {
        if lhs.maj < rhs.maj || lhs.min < rhs.min || lhs.patch < rhs.patch { return true }
        return false
    }

    var maj: Int
    var min: Int
    var patch: Int

    var formatted: String {
        return "\(maj).\(min).\(patch)"
    }
}

let v1 = Version(maj: 1, min: 2, patch: 2)
let v2 = Version(maj: 1, min: 2, patch: 2)
let v3 = Version(maj: 2, min: 2, patch: 2)
let v4 = Version(maj: 1, min: 3, patch: 2)
let v5 = Version(maj: 1, min: 2, patch: 3)

print (v1 == v2)
print (v1 == v3)
print (v1 > v2)
print (v1 > v3)
print (v1 > v4)
print (v1 > v5)
print (v3 > v4)
print (v3 > v5)

print (v1.formatted)
print (v2.formatted)
print (v3.formatted)
print (v4.formatted)
print (v5.formatted)
```